# Extract data from complicated XML in Oracle

Tags: xml, oracle

Please i want help in extracting data from complicated XML into rows in oracle.
i tried the extractvalue but it gives the error :

**ora-31011 xml parsing failed**

**ora-19202 error occurred in xml processing**

**below the output xml :**

```html
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <s:Body>
      <GetEmploymentStatusMultipleResponse xmlns="http://MSB.Services.Integration.External.ServicesContracts.GOSI.IGOSIService">
         <GetEmploymentStatusMultipleResult xmlns:b="http://MSB.Services.Integration.External.DataContracts.GOSI.MultipleEmploymentStatusStructure" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <b:EmploymentStatusStructure xmlns:c="http://MSB.Services.Integration.External.DataContracts.GOSI.EmploymentStatusStructure">
               <c:EmploymentStatusStructure>
                  <c:Contributor xmlns:d="http://MSB.Services.Integration.External.DataContracts.GOSI.ContributorStructure">
                     <d:ContributorID xmlns:e="http://MSB.Services.Integration.External.DataContracts.GOSI.NationalIdentifierSummaryStructure">
                        <e:NationalID>1086828181</e:NationalID>
                     </d:ContributorID>
                  </c:Contributor>
                  <c:ContributorName xmlns:d="http://MSB.Services.Integration.External.DataContracts.GOSI.PersonNameDetailsStructure">
                     <d:Item xmlns:e="http://MSB.Services.Integration.External.DataContracts.GOSI.PersonNameBodyStructure">
                        <e:Title i:nil="true" xmlns:f="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"/>
                        <e:Prefix i:nil="true" xmlns:f="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"/>
                        <e:FirstName>test1</e:FirstName>
                        <e:SecondName>test2</e:SecondName>
                        <e:ThirdName>test3</e:ThirdName>
                        <e:FourthName i:nil="true"/>
                        <e:LastName>test4</e:LastName>
                        <e:Suffix i:nil="true" xmlns:f="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"/>
                     </d:Item>
                     <d:Language>AR</d:Language>
                  </c:ContributorName>
                  <c:ContributorStatus>2</c:ContributorStatus>
               </c:EmploymentStatusStructure>
            </b:EmploymentStatusStructure>
         </GetEmploymentStatusMultipleResult>
      </GetEmploymentStatusMultipleResponse>
   </s:Body>
 </s:Envelope>
```

Comment: The XML is syntactically valid.  Show the COMPLETE error message and any stack trace.

Comment: Hi Jim,


i tried to retrieve the tag 'NationalId' by running the command : 


  Select Extractvalue(X, '/s:Envelope/s:Body/GetEmploymentStatusMultipleResponse/GetEmploymentStatusMultipleResult/b:EmploymentStatusStructure/c:EmploymentStatusStructure/c:Contributor/d:ContributorID/e:NationalID')
    Into Var1
    From Dual;

Comment: the error message is :

**ORA-31011: XML parsing failed ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing**

**LPX-00601: Invalid token in: '\s:Envelope\s:Body\GetEmploymentStatusMultipleResponse\GetE‌​mploymentStatusMulti‌​pleResult\b:Employme‌​ntStatusStructure\c:‌​EmploymentStatusStru‌​cture\c:Contributor\‌​d:ContributorID\e:Na‌​tionalID'**

Comment: Please do not add information in comments, [edit] your post instead.

Comment: Looks like it's failing xsd validation.   Check the xsd referenced by `xmlns:e` (`http://MSB.Services.Integration.External.DataContracts.GOSI.PersonNameBodyStructure`)

Answer (score -2):

Use Utl_file or 
Simply 
Select to_char(dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select* from ur_table') ) as xml_data from dual;